# local storage issue with login users

Tags: vue.js

Here I am using local storage. Here the use case is in our site we have two users like one is business user and other is  personal user. So here is a personal is login in with personal user then all the filled values are saving in local storage and the same user login in with his business user mail then i am sseing the same value previously filled in personal login.
So we dont want to show the the value which is filled in personal user that should not show in business user so how to achieve this please help me
local storage for two different logins with same mail and same user but the login is business and personal

*schema*

```
schema_Real_Estate: {
            fields: [{
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Garages",
                required: true,
                model: "Garages",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "job_title"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Basement",
                required: true,
                model: "Basement",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "Experience"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Roof",
                required: true,
                model: "Roof",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "job_title"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Exterior",
                required: true,
                model: "Exterior",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "Experience"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Cooling",
                required: true,
                model: "Cooling",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "job_title"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Heating",
                required: true,
                model: "Heating",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "Experience"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Elementary school",
                required: true,
                model: "Elementary_school",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "job_title"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Middle school",
                required: true,
                model: "Middle_school",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "Experience"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "High school",
                required: true,
                min: '',
                model: "High_school",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "job_title"]
            }]
        },
```

*local storage*

```
// Loading the model from the localStorage
if(localStorage.getItem('model') !== null) this.model = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('model'));

// Saving the model to the localStorage
localStorage.setItem('model', JSON.stringify(this.model));
```

Comment: a quick prolly dumb suggestion, clear the persistent data on login.

Comment: sorry. But i didn't get you